# How to get the id of next tr in table using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<table>
<tr id ="tr_id_1">
    <td >
        Blah
    </td
    <td>
        Blah
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id ="tr_id_2">
    <td>
        Blah
    </td>
    <td>
    Blah
    </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

i have got the id of first tr using jquery

```
var first_tr_id = tr_id_1     // id of first tr
```

now by using this id how to get the id of next tr
   i have tried like this

```
var nextId = ('#'+first_tr_id ).next("tr").attr("id");
```

but its giving **("#" + row_id).next is not a function** error ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You code lacks the jQuery `$`

```
var nextId = $('#'+first_tr_id ).next("tr").attr("id");
```

Also an id is a string, so you should set your variable like so :

```
var first_tr_id = 'tr_id_1';    // id of first tr
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try in this way..

```
var nextId = $('#'+first_tr_id ).next("tr").attr("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in assigning a variable:

```
var first_tr_id = tr_id_1
```

it should be inside quote

```
var first_tr_id = "tr_id_1"
```

Also, to get all the IDs, you can use the following code:

```
$("table tr").each(function(index) {
   alert($(this).id());
}
```

Comment: You don't really need `.each()`, as you can give `.next()` a selector.